# Anylogic Agents are stuck around the corner

Tags: anylogic

I am running an evacuation simulation and when I click on the evacuation button, I find that people get stuck in front of a corner before the exit during their escape, but the outer curve allows this space for more people to escape, how do I deal with this error?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcYhD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IYaD.png)

The best result should be that this space is fully utilised for escape in order to reduce evacuation time.Feel free to ask any questions if it is helpful to fix this error.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a forum for developers, about programming. You problem is a software specific issue. You should better get in contact with the support team of that specific application to have relevant help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The pedestrian library is a black-box that you can not influence much. Either give your peds more space, make them move slower or accept the limitations of the library.

However, given that it is AnyLogic, you can always create your own custom pedestrians or even a full-blown pedestrian dynamics simulation from scratch (but that is a hole new level of skill needed)

PS: Only use the `anylogic` tag, else other SOF users get confused

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience.
So this is a problem that can't be solved by pedestrian libraries alone. I have read about building your own agents, but that's too hard for me. I wonder if there is a compromise solution to this problem?

Comment: Just playing with the ped library blocks and your layout. But don't forget: this is a problem that ALL pedestrian tools share to a degree: the easier it gets for you to model stuff, the less control you have about the inner workings...